# Moment onSameOrBefore function is always false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm using moment to validate a date input, and i'm having a problem with the sameOrBefore function.

This is my code:

```
    const today = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    const legal = moment({today}).subtract(18, 'years').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
    console.log('hoy',today);
    console.log('edad legal', legal);
    const before = moment(value).isSameOrBefore({legal});
    console.log('before',before);
    if (before === false){
        toastError('Ingrese una fecha valida');
        return;
    }
```

And my input

```
<Form.Control 
      className="text-field" 
      type="string" 
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      placeholder="Ingresá tu fecha de nacimiento" />
```

And i'm trying with any date before 2002 that's the value of the "legal" date and the function returns false, no matter what date i put on the input.
For example, i'm writing 03/03/1990 as the value and the isSameOrBefore function returns false.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the right formatting for the moment object to calculate the difference .

This will do the job for you.

```js
let input = "10/01/2002";
let legal = moment().subtract(18, "years");
let result = moment(input, "DD/MM/YYYY").isSameOrBefore(legal);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i already found an answer, i just had to add the wanted format inside the moment() like this:

```
const before = moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY").isSameOrBefore({legal}, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```